Proving $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{6^3}(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt3\pi^3)$ and relating similar series to $\zeta(s)$ algebraically
I have been looking at the Hurwitz Zeta Function $\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}}$ in an exploratory manner recently. In particular I have come across the series $ \zeta(3,\frac{1}{6})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{6})^3}$.This is clearly directly related to the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}$ by a constant multiple of $\frac{1}{6^3}$.
Looking at this sum in wolfram alpha or similar programs tells me that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{6^3}\left(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt3\pi^3\right).$$ My question is simply where is this coming from? In general for other values of $s$, such as $s=2$ with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}$ don't result in direct relations to $\zeta(2)$ when plugged into these programs.
Is this due to some relation with the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{32}$ in some combination with constant multiples of $\zeta(3)$ to get the result?
I am not seeing quite how to obtain this result and more importantly how much the result generalizes to different powers. Does it relate to the Dirichlet Beta Function $\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$evaluated at special values in general? Guidance on the particular case as well as potential other cases when rational $a=\frac{p}{q}$ values of the hurwitz zeta function $\zeta(s,a)$ can be algebraically related to $\zeta(s)$ along with some special constants would be highly valuable for my exploration.

This is an answer from the ground-up to prove this identity using only basic algebra and contour integration.
Claim $1$: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)^3} = \frac78\zeta(3)$
Proof: From $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^3} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n)^3} + \frac1{(2n-1)^3} = \zeta(3)$ it follows $$\frac18\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)^3} = \zeta(3) \iff \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)^3} = \frac78\zeta(3)$$
Claim $2$: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} + \frac1{(6n+5)^3} = \frac{91}{108}\zeta(3)$
Proof: From the previous claim, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} + \frac1{(6n+3)^3} + \frac1{(6n+5)^3} =\frac78\zeta(3)$$ so it follows $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} + \frac1{(6n+5)^3}\right) + \frac1{27}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)^3} =\frac78\zeta(3)$$ where again applying the previous claim yields $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} + \frac1{(6n+5)^3}=\frac{91}{108}\zeta(3)$$
Claim $3$: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} - \frac1{(6n+5)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{18\sqrt 3}$
Proof: Take $f(z)=\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)(6z+1)^3}$. Consider a circular contour $C$ centred at origin whose radius $R$ grows as $n+\frac12$ where $n\in \mathbb Z$. Consider $I=\oint_C f(z)\mathrm dz$. By the estimation lemma, $$|I|\le \frac{2\pi R}{(6R-1)^3}$$ and thus taking $R\to \infty$ gives $I\to 0$. Then evaluating the integral by residue theorem $I =2\pi i\sum_k\operatorname{Res}(f, r_k)$ gives $$0=-\frac{\pi^2}{18\sqrt 3} + \sum_{n\to -\infty}^{\infty} \frac1{\pi (6n+1)^3}$$
since $f$ has a residue at order $3$ at $-\frac16$ and simple residues at integers. We can rewrite as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n-1)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} - \frac1{(6n+5)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{18\sqrt 3}$$

Adding the results of claims $2$ and $3$ gives $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{36\sqrt 3} + \frac{91}{216}\zeta(3) = \frac1{216}\left(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt 3\pi^3\right)$$ and taking the difference instead gives $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(6n+5)^3} = \frac1{216}(91\zeta(3)-2\sqrt 3 \pi^3)$$

This specific result is proven using that (by obvious factoring) $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+2)^3}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+4)^3}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+6)^3}=\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+3)^3}=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{6^3}$$
so if we denote by $A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}$ and $B=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+5)^3}$ we get that $$A+B=\frac{182\zeta(3)}{6^3}$$
But now a Fourier series easy exercise gives us for $0 \le x \le \pi$ that  $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{\sin (2n+1)x}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^2x-\pi x^2}{8}$$
In particular for $x=\pi/3$ we get that $$\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}(A-B)=\frac{\pi^3}{36}$$ so $$A-B=\frac{4\sqrt 3 \pi^3}{6^3}$$ so adding the two relations gives us the required result $$A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=\frac{91\zeta(3)}{6^3}+\frac{2\sqrt 3 \pi^3}{6^3}$$ and similarly one gets the analogue result for $B=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+5)^3}$

(Too long for a comment.) To put your question in context, the following are special cases of a general result due to Ramanujan,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(3n+1)^3} = \frac{13}{27}\zeta(3)+\frac{2}{81\sqrt3}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(3n+2)^3} = \frac{13}{27}\zeta(3)-\frac{2}{81\sqrt3}\pi^3\\$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(4n+1)^3} = \frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{64}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(4n+3)^3} = \frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{64}\pi^3\\$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(6n+1)^3} = \frac{91}{6^3}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{36\sqrt3}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(6n+5)^3} = \frac{91}{6^3}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{36\sqrt3}\pi^3$$
By changing the exponent from $s=3$ to $s=5$, similar nice results for the three pairs can be found using only $\zeta(5)$ and $\pi^5$. And so on for other odd values $s$.

Addendum (a day later): To find analogous forms on the RHS for other "modulus", we have to use more than one infinite sum on the LHS. For example, let $\phi$ be the golden ratio,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{(5n+1)^3} + \frac1{(5n+2)^3}\right) = \frac{62}{125}\zeta(3)+\frac{2\times5^{1/4}(\phi^{5/2}+\phi^{-5/2})}{625}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{(5n+3)^3} + \frac1{(5n+4)^3}\right) = \frac{62}{125}\zeta(3)-\frac{2\times5^{1/4}(\phi^{5/2}+\phi^{-5/2})}{625}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{(10n+1)^3} + \frac1{(10n+3)^3}\right) = \frac{217}{500}\zeta(3)+\frac{5^{1/4}(\phi^{7/2}+\phi^{-7/2})}{500}\pi^3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{(10n+7)^3} + \frac1{(10n+9)^3}\right) = \frac{217}{500}\zeta(3)-\frac{5^{1/4}(\phi^{7/2}+\phi^{-7/2})}{500}\pi^3\\$$
though closed-forms for other pairings are also possible. However, for modulus $7$ and $14$, it seems now we have to use three sums on the LHS.

I was able to derive this from three main identities of the Hurwitz Zeta function. In order: special values at negative integers, a particular version of the reflection identity, and the multiplication identity:
\begin{align}
\zeta\left(-2,a\right) &= -\frac{B_3(a)}{3} = -\frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^2}{2} - \frac{a}{6} \\
\sum_{r = 1}^5 \zeta(-2, \tfrac{r}{6})\sin\tfrac{2\pi r}{6} &= \frac{6\Gamma(3)}{(12\pi)^3}\cos(\pi)\left(\zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) - \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6}) \right)\\
6^3\zeta(3) &= \sum_{n=1}^6\zeta(3,\tfrac{n}{6})
\end{align}
By calculating the LHS of the second equation explicitly we will get
$$\frac{-1}{12\sqrt{3}} = \frac{-12}{(12\pi)^3}\left(\zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) - \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6}) \right) $$
Or
$$ \zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) - \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6})  = \frac{12\pi^3}{\sqrt{3}} = 4\sqrt{3}\pi^3$$
Then by looking at the third equation from above, we can group the terms to solve for $\zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6})$ in terms of $\zeta(3)$.
\begin{align*}
6^3\zeta(3) = \sum_{n=1}^6\zeta(3,\tfrac{n}{6}) &= \zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6}) + \left(\zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{3}) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{2}{3}) \right) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{2}) + \zeta(3)\\ 
&= \zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6}) + (3^3+1)\zeta(3) + (2^3 +1)\zeta(3) + \zeta(3)\\
\zeta(3, \tfrac{1}{6}) + \zeta(3, \tfrac{5}{6}) &= (6^3 - 3^3 - 2^3 -3) \zeta(3) = 182\zeta(3)
\end{align*}
(try expanding the series groupings to see for yourself that this works.)
Now add the two equations and divide by two and we get the desired identity:
$$\zeta(3,\tfrac{1}{6}) = 91\zeta(3) + 2\pi^3\sqrt{3}. $$

Another reduction formula is
$$I_{6,1}=I_{3,1}-\frac18I_{3,2}$$
where $I_{a,b}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(an+b)^3}$.
Proof:
By definition of Hurwitz zeta function,
$$I_{6,1}=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1-e^{-6x}}dx\\
=\frac14
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1-e^{-3x}}dx+\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1+e^{-3x}}dx\\
=\frac12I_{3,1}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+1)^3}\\
=\frac12I_{3,1}+\frac12I_{6,1}-\frac1{16}I_{3,2}.
$$
Now, we can use the results in Tito Piezas's answer to conclude.
